# How to proof the token claims in a .NET Core Web Api for Azure Active Directory security check

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, policy

When a POST request is incomming for authorisation I will proof the claims of the token. My code you find below. I set breakponts on every line. But from the line

```
`    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>`
```

the compiler jumps direct to the end of the method.
Do I need some thing else before I do this proof or do I need to change the syntax. 
Would be lovely to get help.
Frank

```
`    services.AddAuthorization(configure =>
{
    configure.AddPolicy("AccessControllerClaimGroupGUIDPolic", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            return context.User.HasClaim(c =>
            {
                return (c.Type == "groups" && AllowedClaimsGroupIds.Contains(c.Value)) || (c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" && AllowedClaimsOId.Contains(c.Value));
            });
        });
    });
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

@Frank,

Can you try below code:-

```js
 policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    {
                        var checkIfUserHasClaim= context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                        {
                            c.Type == "groups" && AllowedClaimsGroupIds.Contains(c.Value) || (c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" && AllowedClaimsOId.Contains(c.Value));
                        });
                        return checkIfUserHasClaim;
                    })
```

```js
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            bool hasClaim = HttpContext.User.HasClaim(c =>
                               c.Type == "groups" || (c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
                           );
           // return hasClaim;
            return View();
        }
```

[image]